# How to use multiple link in .goto(url) puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

```
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


(async () => {

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto('url/c-0');
            await page.waitForSelector('.box-chap');
            const element = await page.$(".box-chap");
            const content = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);

            console.log(content + "chapter");

    } catch (error) {

    }
})();
```

Hi all, currently i wanna to loop then : 
url/c-0' 
url/c-1'
url/c-2'
.....

please give me solutions thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop your job. You could create a forloop to loop all chapters which you want to crawl (if your chapter urls have the same format).

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


(async () => {

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const endOfChapterNumber = 10; // number of chapters
    for (const c = 0; c <= endOfChapterNumber; c++) {
      const chapterUrl = 'url/c-' + c;
      await page.goto(chapterUrl);
      await page.waitForSelector('.box-chap');
      const element = await page.$(".box-chap");
      const content = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);

      console.log(content + " chapter: " + c);
    }
  } catch (error) {

  }
})();
```